# Postgres-specific performance tips for django test suite

Tags: django, postgresql, testing

I typically run my test suites on an in-memory SQLite3 DB.  However, I have some projects that absolutely require postgres and raise exceptions with SQLite3.  In these cases, how can I improve speed?

I have one test config that runs in 2.97s in sqlite vs. 89.71s in postgres.  I mean that's crazy.

I have turned fsync off in postgres - that got me from 101.59s to 89.71s.

Comment: don't keep fsync off.  Data corruption can happen that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your server configuration can certainly have an impact on this speed and turning fsync off will make the table creation faster which is a big part of the initial start up cost.

Another part of this is how Django handles fixtures which can seriously hurt performance if you have a large number of fixtures. Django loads fixtures and rolls back the transaction for each test method (not each test class). There is a third-party app [django-fasttest](https://github.com/machinalis/django-fasttest) which uses savepoints after the fixture loading to optimize this loading. [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) has similar optimizations for re-using previously created databases and fixture bundling.

Answer (score 0):

What's your current configuration? Check the [wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) as well.

And start logging slow queries to find the real problems.